# How do you authenticate against Thrift HBase from .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, hbase, thrift

We have a .NET application talking to HBase using Thrift.  The Thrift server is configured to do pass through authentication (Kerberos).  We have a keytab.

How do we implement the authentication from the .NET application?  All the examples I've seen are in Java.  Has anyone done this from .NET?

Comment: It's usually pretty straightforward to rewrite Java into C#. What have you tried so far, and what errors are you getting?

Comment: The Java code examples use the javax.security.auth framework.  Can that reliably be translated to System.Security in .NET?  In reading this doc https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/82tywhc6(v=vs.80).aspx , I find the phrase "... which has different behavior" troubling.

(To be clear, I know there's most likely a way to make this work.  I'm just wondering if anyone else has gone down this path before.)

Comment: @yoliho,       Could you please tell what are the configurations to be added for HBase thrift server with kerberos configuration.?

Comment: @yoliho Did you got any solution? Can you share details if any?

Comment: @Kumar No, unfortunately I never found a solution.  Some alternative approaches are:  1. Use network level security to improve your security profile.  2. Rewrite in Java. :)

Comment: Thanks for the update @yoliho

Answer (score 1):

There is an RPC framework that uses the standard thrift Protocol named "thrifty", and it is the same effect as using thrift IDL to define the service, that is, thrify can be compatible with code that uses thrift IDL, so it is cross-platform.

you can use its client

```
[ThriftStruct]
public class LogEntry
{

    [ThriftConstructor]
    public LogEntry([ThriftField(1)]String category, [ThriftField(2)]String message)
    {
        this.Category = category;
        this.Message = message;
    }

    [ThriftField(1)]
    public String Category { get; }

    [ThriftField(2)]
    public String Message { get; }
}

ThriftSerializer s = new ThriftSerializer(ThriftSerializer.SerializeProtocol.Binary);
byte[] s = s.Serialize<LogEntry>();

s.Deserialize<LogEntry>(s);



[ThriftService("scribe")]
public interface IScribe
{
    [ThriftMethod("getMessages")]
    List<LogEntry> GetMessages();

    [ThriftMethod]
    ResultCode Log(List<LogEntry> messages);
}

public class Scribe : IScribe
{
    public List<LogEntry> GetMessages()
    {
        return new List<LogEntry>
        {
            new LogEntry { Category = "c1", Message = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() },
            new LogEntry { Category = "c2", Message = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() },
            new LogEntry { Category = "c3", Message = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() }
        };
    }

    public ResultCode Log(List<LogEntry> messages)
    {
        return ResultCode.TRY_LATER;
    }
}
```

you can try it: https://github.com/endink/Thrifty